# How to prevent history.back() from going back to login page

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I have a back button in my application which on click should return to parent page. I am using `history.back()` for the purpose . However I am not able to prevent it from going back to login.

Comment: You should specify what are you using, for example jQuery, AngularJs, or plain Javascript. Also it would be nice if you post some code so the other people can get the right context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `document.referrer` to check the previous clicked link :

```
if(document.referrer !="http://myloginpage"){ // different then the url login then go back 
   window.history.back()
}
```